# Synchronous angular code with pure typescript class instantiation

Tags: angular, typescript, synchronous

I'm creating a menu with typescript classes to implements my menu item actions. I'm trying to add a loader for menu actions that takes some time but I'm facing a problem I don't understand.

Here is the generic method I call on a menu item click.

```
public item: Item = { name: 'Execute Menu item 1', command: new FirstMenuItem() };

/** method called on every item click */
executeToolbarAction(item: Item) {
    this.menuService.setLoading(true);

    item.command.executeAction('click');

    this.menuService.setLoading(false);
}
```

I'm never able to see the loader because the code directly jumps to the line next to my `executeAction` call. Can someone explain me that?

I know I can use an `observable` like this:

```
item.command.executeAction('click').subscribe(() => {
    this.menuService.setLoading(false);
});
```

But the thing is I want to understand why it doesn't work without that...

I provided a live demo example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sh5wk4).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you tell us what ``excecuteAction`` does ?  if it takes time then have you tried using subject?

Comment: @CruelEngine it handles a huge amount of data and takes at least 5 seconds in my cases. I know I can use a subject but I'd like to understand why this code is not synchrone. The `this.menuService.setLoading(false)` should be called right after the item execution nope?

Comment: to understand that you'll have to understand the asynchronous nature of javascript

Comment: @CruelEngine I don't see any asynchronous calls in my case without `Observable`

Comment: setTimeout used in your example is also asynchronous

Comment: Actually the `setTimeout` makes the example work. But in my real case, I only have a loop on a big array (more than 20k data) and even the `Observable` is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188794/discussion-between-ahbon-and-cruelengine).

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a call back from the `executeAction` method because of async code in setTimeout execute after 3 seconds and it won't wait. So for that best way to use an observable-observer pattern like below using rxjs.

**menu.component.ts**

```
executeToolbarAction(item: Item) {
     this.menuService.setLoading(true);

     item.command.executeAction('click').subscribe( value => {

        //On Call back received hide loader
        this.menuService.setLoading(false);
    })
}
```

**first-menu-item.ts**

```
 public executeAction(context): Observable<boolean> {
    // create observable
    return new Observable((observer) => {

      // observable execution
      setTimeout( () => {
          observer.next(true)
      observer.complete()
      }, 3000);
    })

  }
```

**Synchronous way**: It waits for each operation to complete, after that only it executes the next operation.

**Asynchronous way**: It never waits for each operation to complete, rather it executes all operations in the first GO only. The result of each operation will be handled once the result is available. In your case `this.menuService.setLoading(false);` will not wait for `setTimeout()` Asynchronous code block.

**[Here is forked solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ffhoc2?file=src/app/menu.component.ts)**

Hope this will help!

Comment: You don't get the point. The `item.command.executeAction()` is the method that can take quite long time. I used `setTimeout()` in that class to simulate that.

Comment: so here you need to return callback function in which you can call setLoading(false) try to use rxjs observable pattern

Comment: please have a look at the comment I added on my question

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried that solution and it works. But I would really like to understand why the code without subscription is not synchrone. Any explanation on that?